# Salesforce Partner Cost

Tags: licenses, partner

I can understand the difference between ISV and OEM but can anyone Explain exact steps to become ISV/OEM partner. 
Also I would like to have clarification on some issues. Please help me with following queries.

1. What is the minimum cost to become partner (ISV/OEM)?
2. Is my
   production Org licence is controlled by salesforce even I pay 25%
   revenue to Salesforce per User per APP?. I have to pay per Month to
   salesforce or Its one time cost(25% revenue) for single production
   org and app ?
3. I belongs to Asia and plan to deliver my
   application in Asia so is there any variation on the cost for
   revenue ?
4. I have to pay security review fee ($2700) while
   joining time (before releasing my App)?
5. What is the criteria to
   become SF partner? They didn't mentioned exactly but I heard form
   some source that I must have SF certification (Dev/Adv Dev etc) to
   join? Is it correct?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> 1) What is the minimum cost to become partner (ISV/OEM)?

Becoming an **ISV partner costs nothing**. The tools (all you can eat developer orgs, partner support, technical library, tutorial material, training courses and webinars) are free. Listing an app costs money.

To list on the **AppExchange** and license your application to Salesforce customers will cost you the initial security review fee of **$2700** (then renewed annually for **$150**) and **15%** of your app's revenue. This is known as the **Standardized** partner program.

> 2) Is my production org license required even I pay 15% revenue to Salesforce per user per app?

Once you have paid the Security Review fee, Salesforce will give you two Enterprise Edition licenses gratis which you can use to administer your Licenses, Subscriptions, Orders etc. But yes, additional licenses must be purchased at full cost (**$135** per person per month).

> 3) I plan to deliver my application in Asia so is there any variation on the cost for revenue?

No.

> 4) I have to pay security review fee ($2700) while joining time (before releasing my App)?

No. For free you can become a partner, seek support, develop and test your application. Only when you want to list your application on the AppExchange will you be required to pay the security review fee.

> 5) What is the criteria to become SF partner? I heard that I must have certification to join?

Registration itself carries no requirements. As opposed to the **ISV partner** program, the **Consulting partner** program ("Cloud Alliance") is more about generating sales and delivering implementations. But if you want to participate in a [tier program](http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_ConsultPartnerRequire.pdf) (silver / gold / platinum) there are competency, certification, revenue and customer satisfaction requirements.

Comment: Hi, I am still confusing about some points. Please help me regarding this.In what basis we have to Pay 15% or 25% revenue. It is per user/per month? If so then what is the amount I should pay to Salesforce If I charge my customer for one time or yearly basis regardless of no of users? I have to pay to salesforce if I want more users in same Production Org? I have to pay for new Production org for same app? Thanks

Comment: If you use the so-called 'Checkout' program, Salesforce will handle your billing and invoicing on your behalf. In the case of the ISVforce partnership they remit the remaining 85% to you.

Comment: On the 15% - at least for software products, you will pay 15% of revenue however you sell your product - online via Checkout (good if customer can evaluate and buy your product quickly) or offline via direct sales or resellers (better for more complex products).  In latter case, you are contractually required to record your sales and notify Salesforce, paying them 15% - the Channel Order App that you install in your ISV business org helps with this.  Best if you read the ISVforce guide if you are going to become an ISV i.e. selling app as product.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the partner org costs? I just had my partner org "expire" and it said my trial ended. How does one get a permanent partner org?